# Passing an object out of a response handler

Tags: swift, asynchronous, callback

Please help me understand why I cannot alter / pass an object out of an http request. In below example I have declared variable 'someVar' and have altered it within the request handler. However the print statement returns 5 both in the init and at the end of the function.

```
var someVar = 5

init () { 

    getHtml() 

    print(self.someVar)

}

func getHtml() {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://www.google.com/")
        .response { (request, response, data, error) in

        self.someVar = 10

    }

print(self.someVar)

}
```

Questions:

1. Why doesn't it print out a '10' in both cases?
2. How do I alter an object within the request handler?

I apologize ahead of time for bad terminology or if this is a strange question. I am new to Swift and this is my first Stack Overflow question.

Comment: `request` is asynchronous. It's likely that you hit `print` before the block has a chance to execute.

Answer (score 0):

1) It doesn't print "10" because in both cases

```
print(self.someVar)
```

is executed BEFORE

```
self.someVar = 10
```

This is because your request is an asynchronous one. This means that it will return whenever it finishes and will trigger a completion block that you specified. However, this request is not blocking your code and so next line is executed immediately.

2) The way you alter your object is correct and is working. It is just that you do not see the result because both of your `print()` are called before the object is altered. Change you code to:

```
var someVar = 5

init () { 

    getHtml()

}

func printVar() {
    print("My variable is now \(self.someVar)")
}

func getHtml() {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://www.google.com/")
        .response { (request, response, data, error) in

        self.someVar = 10
        self.printVar()
    }

print("My variable is still \(self.someVar)")

}
```

Run this code and you will see that first you get a line "My variable is still 5" and then after some delay you will get "My variable is now 10". I hope this will help you to understand how completion handlers in asynchronous requests work.

I have put the second `print()` into a separate function to illustrate how you can call some function to notify your class that request has returned and it is now possible to use the data which came with it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It is deeply appreciated.